# Multiple errors when using batch file and command to unzip files recursively

Tags: batch-file, command, unzip

I'm using the following command in a batch file to recursively unzip files into folder with the name same as the zip file.

```
@echo off
for /R %%I IN (' dir /d /s *.zip ') DO (
    "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -y -o"%%~dpI\%%~nI" "%%I" 
)
```

[image]

I have a zip file such as abc.zip, this zip contains another zip such as mns.zip.
So when I run the bat file, the command unzips all files correctly.
That is, a folder abc is created with contents of abc.zip, and inside this folder mns.zip is unzipped as well to a folder.
Works as I want. However I get a lot of errors with the same message on the command prompt. I want to avoid that and run the bat file without errors.

[image]

Here's the error again:

> System ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> 7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
>
> Scanning the drive for archives:
>
> ERROR: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is
>   incorrect. D:\Unzip_folders\New folder\23Nov2015\error_log.17112015\d

Please help me with this.. How do I get rid of these errors?

Comment: Note that the error comes for all sub files/folders inside the zip file being worked upon for extraction.

Comment: Provide information as image iff they can't be posted as text (readable, searchable, etc).

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do, assuming the program is working correctly, would be to suppress all the error output.

To do this, you would append `> nul 2> nul` to the 7zip command. This redirects all warnings and error output to null. If you'd like to only redirect errors, only include nul 2. Note that this probably isn't the best solution, but if you judt want to get rid of errors this will work